# Regex to match lines that access a certain port and particular packets

Tags: regex

New to Linux and the only way I can get this to work is by using the awk command unfortunately the main directions specify to not use awk.

this is what I got

```
#!/bin/sh
#comment Write a single RegEx to match the lines that access port 22 and only those packets
grep '\s22\s' hw0206.txt | awk {'print $4'}
#comment grep returns the whole line with matched string
#comment \s22\s regular expression to match any string containing 22 preceded or succeeded by white space
```

[instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUPqh.jpg)

Write a single RegEx to match the lines that access port 22 and only those packets, and then return the IP address

```
Input file (hw0206.txt) Expected output of script
date time protocol ip-address port packet-size
2022-02-21 19:22:19 TCP 22.101.2.24 22 24
2018-22-22 02:25:12 UDP 10.221.7.22 2135 222
2200-05-22 22:26:22 UDP 22.122.6.62 2160 22
2012-22-20 15:43:22 TCP 10.121.7.222 22 122
1228-02-10 02:22:02 UDP 22.102.2.62 2089 22 
date time protocol ip-address port packet-size
2022-02-21 19:22:19 TCP 22.101.2.24 22 24
2018-22-22 02:25:12 UDP 10.221.7.22 2135 222
2200-05-22 22:26:22 UDP 22.122.6.62 2160 22
2012-22-20 15:43:22 TCP 10.121.7.222 23 122
1228-02-10 02:22:02 TCP 22.102.2.62 22 22
2100-05-25 21:26:22 UDP 22.112.63.62 2122 22
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no, self paced tutorial. trying to teach myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can match something that should not be part of the result:

```
grep -Po '(\d+\.){3}\d+(?=\s22\s)' hw0206.txt
```

In this case, I would prefer `awk` which gives a more readable solution:

```
awk '$5 == 22 {print $4}' hw0206.txt
```